# Adaptedness of Solution to SPDE

Tags: probability, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

I'm trying to understand existence of solutions to SDPEs of the form
$$
dX = AXdt + F(t,X)dt + B(t,X)dW
$$
from the Hilbert space point of view, following Da Prato & Zabcyzk.  They rely on the standard fixe point method, showing that if the interval $[0,T]$, is sufficiently small, the mapping
$$
\mathcal{K}(Y)(t)= S(t)\xi + \int_0^t S(t-s)F(t,Y)dt + S(t-s)B(t,Y)dW
$$
has a fixed point in the space
$$
C([0,T];L^2(\Omega, \mathbb{P};H))
$$
equipped with the norm
$$
\|X\|_T^2= \sup_{0\leq t\leq T}\mathbb{E}\|X(t)\|_H^2.
$$
The existence argument is standard, using the sequence $X_0 =\xi$, $X_{n+1} = \mathcal{K}(X_n)$.

What I am curious/unsure about is the adaptedness, both of the sequence and the limiting solution.  Assuming $\xi$ is $\mathcal{F}_0$, how can I see that:

1. Each $X_n$ is adapted
2. The limit, $X$, is also adapted

Comment: Is it possible that you forgot an integral in the definition of $\mathcal{K}$?

Comment: do you mean against the stochastic term?  I had meant that single integral to be against both the $dt$ and the $dW$.  I will edit if you think that would be helpful.

Comment: I think it follows inductively. $X_0$ is measurable as a constant. The stochastic integral is a martingale and hence $X_n$ is adapted.

Comment: I can see the merit to an inductive argument, but I could use some tips on filling in the details.